# Do not html encode string in asp.net razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm following the code on [here](http://www.playground.webpirates.nl/MvcJqGrid/) in razor syntax. I end up with this:

I tried this:

```
@{Html.Grid("basic")
    .setCaption("Basic Grid")
    .addColumn(new Column("JobId")
        .setLabel("Id"))
    .addColumn(new Column("Title"))
    .addColumn(new Column("CreatedDate"))
    .setUrl(Url.Action("Jobs"))
    .setAutoWidth(true)
    .setRowNum(10)
    .setRowList(new int[]{10,15,20,50})
    .setViewRecords(true)
    .setPager("pager");}
```

and its displays nothing. I had it starting with just `@` and it encoded the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@(new MvcHtmlString(Html.Grid("basic")
.setCaption("Basic Grid")
.addColumn(new Column("JobId")
    .setLabel("Id"))
.addColumn(new Column("Title"))
.addColumn(new Column("CreatedDate"))
.setUrl(Url.Action("Jobs"))
.setAutoWidth(true)
.setRowNum(10)
.setRowList(new int[]{10,15,20,50})
.setViewRecords(true)
.setPager("pager").ToString())
```

Grid should return `MvcHtmlString` (or just `IHtmlString`) if you want it not to be encoded. The best solution is to write extension method called `ToMvcHtmlString()`, that returns proper value. Then you would just use `Html.Grid().ToMvcHtmlString()`. It is better than creating objects inside of view.

Comment: I'm looking at their source, seems they do not return a string, but some object.

Comment: @Lol coder: ToString() method surely returns string. Look at this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@{ var grid = Html.Grid("basic")
.setCaption("Basic Grid")
.addColumn(new Column("JobId")
    .setLabel("Id"))
.addColumn(new Column("Title"))
.addColumn(new Column("CreatedDate"))
.setUrl(Url.Action("Jobs"))
.setAutoWidth(true)
.setRowNum(10)
.setRowList(new int[]{10,15,20,50})
.setViewRecords(true)
.setPager("pager");
}

Html.Raw(grid.ToString());
```

Better is that grid.ToString() returns an IHtmlString so you don't need to Html.Raw it